# How to prevent undo/redo event which fires outside the `<input>` element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to prevent redo/undo operations in my input box, but when I press cmd+z without focusing on the input box, the text in the input box will still be undone.

```js
// stackoverflow 'Search...' input
const input = document.getElementsByName('q')[0];

input.addEventListener('beforeinput', e => {
  if (e.inputType === 'historyUndo' || e.inputType === 'historyRedo') {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('undo/redo prevented');
  }
}, { capture: true });
```

I tried to use `document.addEventListener('beforeinput', ...)`, but I cannot distinguish whether the target of the event is my input box. What should I do to prevent it without affecting other input elements?

edit: What I mean is: When I blur the input and press cmd+z, the input will regain focus and undo my last change, without `beforeinput` fires on the input. I cannot prevent undo operations in this scene.

Comment: *"...but when I press cmd+z without focusing on the input box, the text in the input box will still be redo."* Did you mean *"...be **un**done."*?

Comment: you don't want it to prevent when out of focus? or what ?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent Ctrl+Z when the mouse pointer is no longer in the  element, you need to monitor keyboard events on your website and check whether the user has pressed Ctrl+Z or not. You can then handle or prevent the undo event depending on your requirements.

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById('your-input-element');
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === 'z') {
    if (document.activeElement !== inputElement) {
      // Suppress the undo (Ctrl+Z) event here
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log('Undo has been prevented');
    }
  }
});
```

Above, I use the keydown event to track when the user presses Ctrl+Z and check whether the mouse pointer is inside the  element or not. If the mouse pointer is not inside an  element, I suppress the undo event.

Comment: This will prevent undo operations on other input elements in the page. I can't to know which input will be undone.

Comment: This will prevent all undo actions on input elements when they do not have focus. If the user wants to undo an input element, they will need to focus on it.

Answer (score 0):

The event target is the element upon which the event was done or an element to which the event bubbled. Since you have created an event handler for a specific input, this event handler will not be executed for inputs where this handler was not specified to handle the event. Hence, you do not need to worry about affecting the history of inputs for whom you did not add the event handler. In my example below you can see two inputs, the first has this event handler which overrides history changes and the other has no such event, so its history changes are not overriden.

```js
const input = document.getElementsByName('q')[0];

input.addEventListener('beforeinput', e => {
  if (e.inputType === 'historyUndo' || e.inputType === 'historyRedo') {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('undo/redo prevented');
  }
}, { capture: true });
```

```html
<input type="text" name="q">
<input type="text">
```